# How to implement Flood-fill algorithms?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on one Paint application wherein I am implementing BucketFill functionality similar to MS paint application.

I have coded it using a couple of FloodFill algorithms but the filling color process is taking too much time.
I am not pretty sure reasons behind it may happen due to the low cache memory, poor algorithm, or it may be taking a lot of time calculating offsets.

Can someone help me out with your Knowledge in Flutter/Dart?

Algorithms tried:

- Recursion Based Approach(4 or 8 connected Method)
- Queue-Based approach
- Stack Based Approach
- QueueLinear Based Approach

With above all the performance is very slow

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class BucketFill {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];
  Uint32List words;
  static int width;
  Color oldColor, pixel;
  int imageWidth;
  int imageHeight;

  Future<List> capturePng(GlobalKey key, Offset offset) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    final rgbaImageData =
        await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
    imageHeight = image.height;
    imageWidth = image.width;
    words = Uint32List.view(rgbaImageData.buffer, rgbaImageData.offsetInBytes,
        rgbaImageData.lengthInBytes ~/ Uint32List.bytesPerElement);
    oldColor = _getColor(words, offset.dx, offset.dy);
    return _floodfill(oldColor, offset.dx, offset.dy);
  }

  Color _getColor(Uint32List words, double x1, double y1) {
    int x = x1.toInt();
    int y = y1.toInt();
    var offset = x + y * imageWidth;
    return Color(words[offset]);
  }

// Queue based approach.
  List<Offset> _floodfill(Color oldColor, double x, double y) {
    Queue<Offset> queue = new Queue();
    Offset temp;
    queue.add(Offset(x, y));
    _points = List.from(_points)..add(queue.first);
    while (queue.isNotEmpty) {
      temp = queue.first;
      queue.removeFirst();
      if (_shouldFillColor(temp.dx + 2, temp.dy)) {
        queue.add(Offset(temp.dx + 2, temp.dy));
        _points.add(Offset(temp.dx + 2, temp.dy));
      }
      if (_shouldFillColor(temp.dx - 2, temp.dy)) {
        queue.add(Offset(temp.dx - 2, temp.dy));
        _points.add(Offset(temp.dx - 2, temp.dy));
      }
      if (_shouldFillColor(temp.dx, temp.dy + 2)) {
        queue.add(Offset(temp.dx, temp.dy + 2));
        _points.add(Offset(temp.dx, temp.dy + 2));
      }
      if (_shouldFillColor(temp.dx, temp.dy - 2)) {
        queue.add(Offset(temp.dx, temp.dy - 2));
        _points.add(Offset(temp.dx, temp.dy - 2));
      }
    }
    _points.add(null);
    return _points;
  }

  bool _shouldFillColor(double x, double y) {
    return (x >= 0 &&
            x < imageWidth &&
            y >= 0 &&
            y < imageHeight &&
            !_points.contains(Offset(x, y)))
        ? _getColor(words, x, y) == oldColor
        : false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: Yes i got but that's is not perfect. We can use fillpath in custom paint.

Comment: Can you please check my question and help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736173/flutter-flood-or-bucket-fill-image/57742142#57742142

Comment: Still did not found any solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just recently made a package for this called [floodfill_image](https://pub.dev/packages/floodfill_image)

Basically I use the [Queue-Linear Flood Fill Algorithm by J. Dunlap](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16405/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith) and ported it into Flutter.

Here's the source code that I use for Flutter:

```dart
//Original algorithm by J. Dunlap queuelinearfloodfill.aspx
//Java port by Owen Kaluza
//Android port by Darrin Smith (Standard Android)
//Flutter port by Garlen Javier
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
class QueueLinearFloodFiller {
  img.Image image;
  int _width = 0;
  int _height = 0;
  int _cachedWidth = -1;
  int _cachedHeight = -1;
  int _fillColor = 0;
  int _tolerance = 8;
  List<int> _startColor = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  List<bool> _pixelsChecked;
  Queue<_FloodFillRange> _ranges;
  QueueLinearFloodFiller(img.Image imgVal, int newColor) {
    image = imgVal;
    _width = image.width;
    _height = image.height;
    setFillColor(newColor);
  }
  void resize(Size size) {
    if (_cachedWidth != size.width.toInt() ||
        _cachedHeight != size.height.toInt()) {
      image = img.copyResize(image,
          width: size.width.toInt(), height: size.height.toInt());
      _width = image.width;
      _height = image.height;
      _cachedWidth = _width;
      _cachedHeight = _height;
    }
  }
  void setTargetColor(int targetColor) {
    _startColor[0] = img.getRed(targetColor);
    _startColor[1] = img.getGreen(targetColor);
    _startColor[2] = img.getBlue(targetColor);
    _startColor[3] = img.getAlpha(targetColor);
  }
  void setTolerance(int value) {
    _tolerance = value.clamp(0, 100);
  }
  int getFillColor() {
    return _fillColor;
  }
  void setFillColor(int value) {
    _fillColor = value;
  }
  void _prepare() {
    // Called before starting flood-fill
    _pixelsChecked = List<bool>.filled(_width * _height, false);
    _ranges = Queue<_FloodFillRange>();
  }
  // Fills the specified point on the bitmap with the currently selected fill
  // color.
  // int x, int y: The starting coords for the fill
  Future<void> floodFill(int x, int y) async {
    // Setup
    _prepare();
    if (_startColor[0] == 0) {
      // ***Get starting color.
      int startPixel = image.getPixelSafe(x, y);
      _startColor[0] = img.getRed(startPixel);
      _startColor[1] = img.getGreen(startPixel);
      _startColor[2] = img.getBlue(startPixel);
    }
    // ***Do first call to floodfill.
    _linearFill(x, y);
    // ***Call floodfill routine while floodfill _ranges still exist on the
    // queue
    _FloodFillRange range;
    while (_ranges.length > 0) {
      // **Get Next Range Off the Queue
      range = _ranges.removeFirst();
      // **Check Above and Below Each Pixel in the Floodfill Range
      int downPxIdx = (_width * (range.y + 1)) + range.startX;
      int upPxIdx = (_width * (range.y - 1)) + range.startX;
      int upY = range.y - 1; // so we can pass the y coord by ref
      int downY = range.y + 1;
      for (int i = range.startX; i <= range.endX; i++) {
        // *Start Fill Upwards
        // if we're not above the top of the bitmap and the pixel above
        // this one is within the color tolerance
        if (range.y > 0 && (!_pixelsChecked[upPxIdx]) && _checkPixel(i, upY)) {
          _linearFill(i, upY);
        }
        // *Start Fill Downwards
        // if we're not below the bottom of the bitmap and the pixel
        // below this one is within the color tolerance
        if (range.y < (_height - 1) &&
            (!_pixelsChecked[downPxIdx]) &&
            _checkPixel(i, downY)) {
          _linearFill(i, downY);
        }
        downPxIdx++;
        upPxIdx++;
      }
    }
  }
  // Finds the furthermost left and right boundaries of the fill area
  // on a given y coordinate, starting from a given x coordinate, filling as
  // it goes.
  // Adds the resulting horizontal range to the queue of floodfill _ranges,
  // to be processed in the main loop.
  //
  // int x, int y: The starting coords
  void _linearFill(int x, int y) {
    // ***Find Left Edge of Color Area
    int lFillLoc = x; // the location to check/fill on the left
    int pxIdx = (_width * y) + x;
    while (true) {
      // **fill with the color
      //pixels[pxIdx] = _fillColor;
      image.setPixelSafe(lFillLoc, y, _fillColor);
      // **indicate that this pixel has already been checked and filled
      _pixelsChecked[pxIdx] = true;
      // **de-increment
      lFillLoc--; // de-increment counter
      pxIdx--; // de-increment pixel index
      // **exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
      if (lFillLoc < 0 ||
          (_pixelsChecked[pxIdx]) ||
          !_checkPixel(lFillLoc, y)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    lFillLoc++;
    // ***Find Right Edge of Color Area
    int rFillLoc = x; // the location to check/fill on the left
    pxIdx = (_width * y) + x;
    while (true) {
      // **fill with the color
      image.setPixelSafe(rFillLoc, y, _fillColor);
      // **indicate that this pixel has already been checked and filled
      _pixelsChecked[pxIdx] = true;
      // **increment
      rFillLoc++; // increment counter
      pxIdx++; // increment pixel index
      // **exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
      if (rFillLoc >= _width ||
          _pixelsChecked[pxIdx] ||
          !_checkPixel(rFillLoc, y)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    rFillLoc--;
    // add range to queue
    _FloodFillRange r = new _FloodFillRange(lFillLoc, rFillLoc, y);
    _ranges.add(r);
  }
  // Sees if a pixel is within the color tolerance range.
  bool _checkPixel(int x, int y) {
    int pixelColor = image.getPixelSafe(x, y);
    int red = img.getRed(pixelColor);
    int green = img.getGreen(pixelColor);
    int blue = img.getBlue(pixelColor);
    int alpha = img.getAlpha(pixelColor);
    return (red >= (_startColor[0] - _tolerance) &&
        red <= (_startColor[0] + _tolerance) &&
        green >= (_startColor[1] - _tolerance) &&
        green <= (_startColor[1] + _tolerance) &&
        blue >= (_startColor[2] - _tolerance) &&
        blue <= (_startColor[2] + _tolerance) &&
        alpha >= (_startColor[3] - _tolerance) &&
        alpha <= (_startColor[3] + _tolerance));
  }
}
// Represents a linear range to be filled and branched from.
class _FloodFillRange {
  int startX;
  int endX;
  int y;
  _FloodFillRange(int startX, int endX, int yPos) {
    this.startX = startX;
    this.endX = endX;
    this.y = yPos;
  }
}
```

Here's a sample gif that would also show how fast this Algorithm in Flutter.

[image]

If you want to know more about the steps I made to port it, you can visit my blog https://www.meekcode.com/blog/flood-fill-in-flutter

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your work and it's amazing. I am using your package in my app and faced one issue. The image quality reduces is there any way to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you help me with this query please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77991379/flood-fill-image-leaking-colors-in-flutter