# Which one fills the image Flood or Bucket in Flutter?

Tags: image-processing, flutter, dart, flood-fill

I am new in Flutter.

I want to select a zone from the below images.
How can I achieve the flood or bucket fill in Flutter?

Can someone help me out with your Knowledge in Flutter Dart..??

[image]

Comment: It's a pretty lengthy process. Hint : https://pub.dev/packages/image

Comment: Do you have any idea like how can I do step by step ?

Comment: Sorry I am not that good with image manipulation in Dart. Wait for some time, someone will surely answer to your query.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently made a package for this called [floodfill_image](https://pub.dev/packages/floodfill_image)

Basically I use the [Queue-Linear Flood Fill Algorithm by J. Dunlap](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16405/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith) and ported it into Flutter.

Please check my answer here: [How to implement Flood-fill algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837641/how-to-implement-flood-fill-algorithms/66067293#66067293)